# Quanteda phrasetotoken does not work

Tags: r, quanteda

**Situation 1**

I get strange results when applying the phrasetotoken function in the Quanteda packages:

```
dict    <- dictionary(list(words = ......*lokale energie productie*......)) 
txt     <- c("I like lokale energie producties) 
phrasetotoken(txt, dict)
```

Problem: Sometimes I get `lokale_energie_producties` back, sometimes incorrectly the original `lokale energie producties`.

The problem seems connected to the dots in the dictionary. These dots are(?) needed to deal with starting and trailing characters (e.g., "1lokale energie productieniveau").

**Situation 2**

When loading in a txt file, the the prasetotoken function does not work at all.

```
txt <- paste(readLines("foo.txt", collapse=" ")
txt <- phrasetotoken(txt, dict)
```

NB. Using the function `readtext` instead of `readLines` throws the following error

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘phrasetotoken’ for signature ‘"readtext", "dictionary"’
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I found the solution for the first problem, the terms in the dictionary must be entered as follows: {.*lokale.* .*energie.* .*producti.*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Situation 1

We've replaced `phrasetotoken()` with a more powerful and flexible function `tokens_compound()`.  It works like this (after some modifications of your code to make it syntactically correct):

```
txt <- c("I like lokale energie producties") 
toks <- tokens(txt)

tokens_compound(toks, list(words = c("*lokale", "energie",  "productie*")))
## tokens from 1 document.
## Component 1 :
## [1] "I"                         "like"                      "lokale_energie_producties"
```

#### Situtation 2

Try the following workflow instead:

```
require(magrittr)  # for the pipes
readtext("foo.txt") %>%
    corpus() %>%
    tokens() %>%
    tokens_compound(sequences = dict)
```